# Laravel Homestead 'apt-get update' gives some 404

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu, apt-get, homestead

Is there some misconfiguration with Homestead 2.1.7 (box 0.4.0) preconfigured sourcelist?

PS. It would be greatly appreciated if Homestead's next versions would include options in configuration files for installing some pre-configured additional packages like MS SQL. Yes not everybody needs them, but with client projects there often comes need for more exotic packages than is found in #laragarden

```
vagrant@homestead:~$ sudo apt-get update
Hit http://apt.postgresql.org trusty-pgdg InRelease                            
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease                              
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security InRelease                       
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Hit http://apt.postgresql.org trusty-pgdg/main amd64 Packages                  
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Get:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates InRelease [64.4 kB]          
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main Sources                    
Ign http://dl.hhvm.com utopic InRelease                                        
Hit http://apt.postgresql.org trusty-pgdg/main i386 Packages                   
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release.gpg                                
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted Sources              
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release.gpg                                
Ign http://dl.hhvm.com utopic Release.gpg                                      
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages                        
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe Sources                
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        
Ign http://dl.hhvm.com utopic Release                                          
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse Sources              
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages                        
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports InRelease                    
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main amd64 Packages             
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        
Ign http://dl.hhvm.com utopic/main amd64 Packages/DiffIndex                    
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg                            
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release                                    
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted amd64 Packages       
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release                                    
Ign http://apt.postgresql.org trusty-pgdg/main Translation-en_US               
Hit http://packages.blackfire.io any InRelease                                 
Get:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main Sources [248 kB]        
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages                        
Ign http://dl.hhvm.com utopic/main i386 Packages/DiffIndex                     
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe amd64 Packages         
Ign http://apt.postgresql.org trusty-pgdg/main Translation-en                  
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse amd64 Packages       
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main i386 Packages              
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted i386 Packages        
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages                        
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe i386 Packages          
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse i386 Packages        
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main Translation-en             
Hit http://packages.blackfire.io any/main amd64 Packages                       
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse Translation-en       
Get:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted Sources [5,359 B] 
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted Translation-en       
Get:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe Sources [147 kB]    
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe Translation-en         
Get:5 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse Sources [5,161 B] 
Hit http://packages.blackfire.io any/main i386 Packages                        
Get:6 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages [689 kB] 
Ign http://dl.hhvm.com utopic/main Translation-en_US                           
Ign http://dl.hhvm.com utopic/main Translation-en                              
Err http://dl.hhvm.com utopic/main amd64 Packages                              
  404  Not Found [IP: 140.211.166.134 80]
Err http://dl.hhvm.com utopic/main i386 Packages                               
  404  Not Found [IP: 140.211.166.134 80]
Get:7 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted amd64 Packages [15.9 kB]
Get:8 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe amd64 Packages [334 kB]
Ign http://packages.blackfire.io any/main Translation-en_US                    
Get:9 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages [13.0 kB]
Get:10 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main i386 Packages [663 kB] 
Ign http://packages.blackfire.io any/main Translation-en                       
Get:11 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted i386 Packages [15.6 kB]
Get:12 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe i386 Packages [335 kB]
Get:13 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse i386 Packages [13.1 kB]
Get:14 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main Translation-en [348 kB]
Get:15 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse Translation-en [6,832 B]
Get:16 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted Translation-en [3,699 B]
Get:17 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe Translation-en [175 kB]
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main Sources                 
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted Sources           
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe Sources             
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse Sources           
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main amd64 Packages          
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted amd64 Packages    
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe amd64 Packages      
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse amd64 Packages    
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main i386 Packages           
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted i386 Packages     
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe i386 Packages       
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse i386 Packages     
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main Translation-en          
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse Translation-en    
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted Translation-en    
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe Translation-en      
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release                                
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Sources                           
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Sources                     
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Sources                       
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Sources                     
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main amd64 Packages                    
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted amd64 Packages              
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe amd64 Packages                
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse amd64 Packages              
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main i386 Packages                     
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted i386 Packages               
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe i386 Packages                 
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse i386 Packages               
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en                    
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Translation-en              
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Translation-en              
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-en                
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en_US                 
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Translation-en_US           
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Translation-en_US           
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-en_US             
Fetched 3,083 kB in 35s (86.1 kB/s)                                            
W: Failed to fetch http://dl.hhvm.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 140.211.166.134 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://dl.hhvm.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 140.211.166.134 80]

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need HHVM you can remove it from sources.

- Connect to vagrant machine:
  `vagrant ssh`
- Remove hhvm:
  `sudo rm -f /etc/apt/sources.list.d/hhvm.list`
- Update packages list:
  `sudo apt-get update`
- Exit from machine:
  `exit`
- Restart machine:
  `vagrant restart --provision`